# Chart.js not showing correctly/install issues

Tags: javascript, charts, installation, chart.js

I am very new to web dev and trying to get chart.js loaded but am having some issues... after reading through the documentation I think I have al the right parts just maybe in the wrong order?

- installed chart.js via nmp and linked to script in header, then added

`<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>` to the body.

after that it seems like you only need (in a script tag in body)...

`var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx[0]).Pie(data,options);`

and then the actually data...

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    },  etc......
```

unfortunately, I don't see anything on the page. chart.js actually has some great documentation but I'm a little lost on the start, any ideas? thanks!

jsfiddle added for clarity! https://jsfiddle.net/bencasalino/tfsy6gxL/

and the tutorial I'm using http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-beautiful-charts-chart-js/

Comment: Consider adding a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a `runnable code snippet` to your question, so we can actual work out what the problem is :).

Comment: thank you! here is my fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/bencasalino/tfsy6gxL/ I am using external libraries though so it wont show up, I just feel like I have the ordering of everything  way wrong either way!

Comment: "I just feel like I have the ordering of everything way wrong either way!" not sure what you mean there... the fiddle should be working as well as possible for those who run it :). "You had HTML <script> tags in the JavaScript section of the fiddle.
You were loading Chart.js with <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js/Chart.js"></script>, where there is no chart.js/Chart.js on JSFiddle (also myjs.js doesn't not exist on their servers)." are probably therefore not helpful I'll just leave them in for the moment... also accept the answer if you think it is good :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the supplied [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bencasalino/tfsy6gxL/) in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444882/chart-js-not-showing-correctly-install-issues?noredirect=1#comment58588161_35444882), but not on your question, you had a few problems:

1. You had HTML `<script>` tags in the `JavaScript` section of the fiddle.
2. You were loading `Chart.js` with `<script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js/Chart.js"></script>`, where there is no `chart.js/Chart.js` on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) (also `myjs.js` doesn't not exist on their servers).
3. You had `var skillsChart = new Chart(context).Pie(data);` *before* your `pieData` array, and not after.
4. `var skillsChart = new Chart(context).Pie(data);` should have been `var skillsChart = new Chart(context).Pie(pieData);` as your array is called `pieData`, not `data`.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfsy6gxL/2/).

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: ah thank you so much, I checked out your js fiddle it all makes much more sense than mine. I am still confused on how you got the chart to actually load. I thought that chart.js was dependent upon the chart.js library to actually load. I can get it working when I put all the js in a script tag at the bottom of the body. But when I externally link `<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>` in the header it breaks.

Comment: @BenjaminCasalino I'm not sure what the problem is on your end, but hopefully these points will help... all you need is: 1. The library, cdn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js) or local. 2. A <canvas> 3. The context 4. Some data 5. A `Chart` Object. Hope this helps! :) (And I appreciate my first accepted question! ;))

Comment: yes thank you it seems to be working now. I just didnt understand how jsfiddle knew what to output without linking to that chart.js library, but I guess it just figured it out :) thanks again!